# (solved) Slam Generated Map Does Not Appear

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few days ago I succeed mapping on my laptop

Now I trying to mapping as hector slam on raspberry pi3 (ubuntu mate)

By the way mapping not work on raspberry

I think the environment of raspberry is equal the environment of laptop

First my procedure is

1. Downloading pakage about this project (Hector_Slam, ros_rplidar)
2. building the files  (catkin make) , setting a port
3. modifying code of mapping_default.launch of hector_mapping file in hector slam.

```
I did not modify anything else
```

The result of implementation is like this

[image: image description]

I changed fixed map : map , laser , base_frame and  and added map on dispaly list (topic : /map)

a error not generate on terminal but also map not appear

what is problem??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290180/(solved)-slam-generated-map-does-not-appear/) by [DongHyeong Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/34513/donghyeong-kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

I attach my tf tree screen shot

please see and tell me why mapping not work

========================================================

This problem is error in building

after initialization raspberrypi , retry to building slam file

It is work

---

Originally posted by [DongHyeong Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/34513/donghyeong-kang/) with karma: 13 on 2018-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-05-04**:
For now I cab only be sure that /hecto_mapping is not publishing any topic with a map. But you hided the terminal with the information about the topics..
I think you should write parameters for the map size and resolution also..

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-05-04**:\

**Comment by [DongHyeong Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/34513/donghyeong-kang/) on 2018-05-04**:
Thank you so much billy
So can I write them in mapping_default.launch?
I’m sorry . Can I see the simple example??

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-05-08**:
https://pastebin.com/vdmjPJet
There you have the file that I use